# Removing the page number in the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` for the standard `book`class

Tags: table-of-contents

How is it possible to remove the figure/table number printed at the beginning  of each line in the list of figures/tables respectively generated by the standard commands `\listoffigures`/`\listoftables` in a document with `book` class?

Perhaps this is a very silly question, solvable by a careful look at Kopka and Daly, however I did not notice it: I need such a style change since, since I was asked to list only the caption and page number of each item in the said lists. The custom environments developed by me so far completely fulfil the task by using the `\addcontentsline` command: however, the standard `figure` and `tabular` follow their standard behaviour in the `book` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package and in your preamble put:

```
\documentclass[...]{book}
% ...
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\def\cftfigpresnum #1\@cftasnum{}  % no figure number
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0em} % no indent before number
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{0em} % no space for number
% and similarly for three \cfttab... macros
\makeatother
% ...
\begin{document}
```

Adjust the `\cft...indent` and `\cft...numwidth` to suit your layout.